# A posed element's child not responding to pose changes

Tags: reactjs, react-pose

`AnimDiv` does not appear to change its style as the `pose` variable changes. The same approach would work with the parent, however the child seems to take only the initial value of whatever's passed to its `pose`, then doesn't care about it on subsequent re-renders.

Why is that so?

```
const AnimDiv = posed.div({
    red: {
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    blue: {
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
});

const AnimationTest = () => {
    const [pose, setPose] = useState("red");
    return (
        <div
            className="animated"
        >
            <AnimDiv
                style={{ position: "absolute", height: "20px", width: "20px" }}

                onClick={() => setPose(x => (x === "blue" ? "red" : "blue"))}
                pose={pose} // only the value from the initial render matters; you may change the pose state variable, but the element will not adjust its style
            ></AnimDiv>
        </div>
    );
};
```

EDIT:
It does respond to pose changes, however for whatever reason it does not switch backgrounds. Opacity, for example, worked.

Answer (score 0):

For `background-color`, the value be cannot be a color literal (such as `red`). Substituting a `rgb(r,g,b)` for it will make the pose work.